# bash - delete list of directories (including their contents)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

The below script gives this error:

```
rm: illegal option -- 4
rm: illegal option -- 5
rm: illegal option -- 4
rm: illegal option -- 3
rm: illegal option -- 2
```

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
keep_no=$1+1
cd "/mydirec/"
rm -rf `ls | sort -nr | tail +$keep_no`
```

I would like the script to accept an argument (of num of direcs to keep) then remove all directories (including their containing files) except for the (number passed in the script - ordering by the numerical direc names in descending order).

ie if /mydirec/ contains these direc names:

```
53
92
8
152
77
```

and the script is called like: bash del.sh 2

then /mydirec/ should contains these direcs (as it removes those that aren't the top 2 in desc order):

```
152
92
```

Can someone please help with the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then 
   echo "syntax is..."
   exit 1
fi
keep_no=$(( $1 + 1 ))
cd "/mydirec/"
IFS='
';    # record separator: only enter inside single quotes
echo rm -rf $(ls | sort -nr | tail +$keep_no)
```

Verify the output of the script **manually**, then execute the script through sh:

```
./your_script.sh | sh -x
```

Answer (score 5):

Should read:

```
rm -rf `ls | sort -nr | tail -n +$keep_no`
```

But it is good practice not to parse ls output. Use find instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
keep_no=$(( $1+1 ))
directory="./mydirec/"
cd $directory
rm -rf `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'| sort -nr | tail -n +$keep_no`
cd -
```

Comment: This find command will only find directories *AND** it will also find current directory `.`

Comment: the question asks for the directory names only. Your other point is right. I updated it. now removes the current directory with sed.

Comment: Though OP seems to be removing files and directories both by using ls command.

Comment: the OP will be accidentally removing files, but the OPs stated need is to remove directories ("ie if /mydirec/ contains these direc names"). I think 'onur gungor' has got it right. (Sorry about US only alpha chars). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter - as mentioned in the question: 'remove all directories (including their containing files)'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave two directories (not to delete) you need to calculate total number of directories. And `xargs` utility is more convenient way to pass a list of arguments to `rm`.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/yourdir"
total_no=`ls | wc -l`
keep_no=$(( $total_no - $1 ))
ls | sort -nr | tail -n $keep_no | xargs rm -rf
```